# Android ListView with images and text in Fragment

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I createad a Navigation Drawer in Android Studio. Inside Fragment of Navigation Drawer I wanted to add a ListView with images and text.But after I running program and clicking on the fragment program crashing with text "Unfortunately, SerialMania has stopped ". What I'm doing wrong?

```
package boiko.taisiia.com.serialmania;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class Date extends Fragment {

// Array of strings storing country names
String[] countries = new String[] {
        "India",
        "Pakistan",
        "Sri Lanka",
        "China",
        "Bangladesh",
        "Nepal",
        "Afghanistan",
        "North Korea",
        "South Korea",
        "Japan"
};

// Array of integers points to images stored in /res/drawable-ldpi/
int[] flags = new int[]{
        R.drawable.ic_menu_camera,
        R.drawable.ic_menu_camera,
        R.drawable.ic_menu_camera,
        R.drawable.ic_menu_camera,
        R.drawable.ic_menu_camera,
        R.drawable.ic_menu_camera,
        R.drawable.ic_menu_camera,
        R.drawable.ic_menu_camera,
        R.drawable.ic_menu_camera,
        R.drawable.ic_menu_camera
};

// Array of strings to store currencies
String[] currency = new String[]{
        "Indian Rupee",
        "Pakistani Rupee",
        "Sri Lankan Rupee",
        "Renminbi",
        "Bangladeshi Taka",
        "Nepalese Rupee",
        "Afghani",
        "North Korean Won",
        "South Korean Won",
        "Japanese Yen"
};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.fragment_date);

    // Each row in the list stores country name, currency and flag
    List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
        hm.put("txt", "Country : " + countries[i]);
        hm.put("cur","Currency : " + currency[i]);
        hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]) );
        aList.add(hm);
    }

    // Keys used in Hashmap
    String[] from = { "flag","txt","cur" };

    // Ids of views in listview_layout
    int[] to = { R.id.flag,R.id.txt,R.id.cur};

    // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
    // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);

    // Getting a reference to listview of main.xml layout file
    ListView listView = ( ListView ) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listview);

    // Setting the adapter to the listView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

Comment: Need to override `onCreateView` method of Fragment class to set layout for current Fragment. currently by using `getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.fragment_date);` you are changing layout of Activity instead of Fragment. see [Creating a Fragment](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/fragments/creating.html) for how to set layout for Fragment.

Comment: Please post your stacktrace.

Comment: you are not follow fragment lifecycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about [fragments](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) Change your code,you can use onCreateView,onViewCreated and onActivityCreated.onCreate method is use initialize Variable,object or receiving Values or objects which from coming Acivity.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);

    tvTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
    ivLogo = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivLogo);

    // Each row in the list stores country name, currency and flag 
    List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
        hm.put("txt", "Country : " + countries[i]);
        hm.put("cur","Currency : " + currency[i]);
        hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]) );
        aList.add(hm);
    } 

    // Keys used in Hashmap 
    String[] from = { "flag","txt","cur" };

    // Ids of views in listview_layout 
    int[] to = { R.id.flag,R.id.txt,R.id.cur};

    // Instantiating an adapter to store each items 
    // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item 
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(v.getContext(), aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);

    // Getting a reference to listview of main.xml layout file 
    ListView listView = ( ListView ) v.findViewById(R.id.listview);

    // Setting the adapter to the listView 
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

remove this code from `onCreate`:

```
getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.fragment_date);
```

and add this method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_date, container, false);
}
```

**UPD**

here is your modified code:

```
package boiko.taisiia.com.serialmania;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class Date extends Fragment {

    // Array of strings storing country names
    String[] countries = new String[] {
            "India",
            "Pakistan",
            "Sri Lanka",
            "China",
            "Bangladesh",
            "Nepal",
            "Afghanistan",
            "North Korea",
            "South Korea",
            "Japan"
    };

    // Array of integers points to images stored in /res/drawable-ldpi/
    int[] flags = new int[]{
            R.drawable.ic_menu_camera,
            R.drawable.ic_menu_camera,
            R.drawable.ic_menu_camera,
            R.drawable.ic_menu_camera,
            R.drawable.ic_menu_camera,
            R.drawable.ic_menu_camera,
            R.drawable.ic_menu_camera,
            R.drawable.ic_menu_camera,
            R.drawable.ic_menu_camera,
            R.drawable.ic_menu_camera
    };

    // Array of strings to store currencies
    String[] currency = new String[]{
            "Indian Rupee",
            "Pakistani Rupee",
            "Sri Lankan Rupee",
            "Renminbi",
            "Bangladeshi Taka",
            "Nepalese Rupee",
            "Afghani",
            "North Korean Won",
            "South Korean Won",
            "Japanese Yen"
    };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    

        // Each row in the list stores country name, currency and flag
        List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
            hm.put("txt", "Country : " + countries[i]);
            hm.put("cur","Currency : " + currency[i]);
            hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]) );
            aList.add(hm);
        }

        // Keys used in Hashmap
        String[] from = { "flag","txt","cur" };

        // Ids of views in listview_layout
        int[] to = { R.id.flag,R.id.txt,R.id.cur};

        // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
        // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);

        // Getting a reference to listview of main.xml layout file
        ListView listView = ( ListView ) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listview);

        // Setting the adapter to the listView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_date, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: @TaisiiaBoiko Remove that line `logger.v` from code.

Comment: you are not follow fragment lifecycle.

Comment: unfortunately, it  crushed again

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

This is not the good way to set your content in your fragment !

**code**

```
public final class YourFragment extends Fragment{

private TextView tvTitle;

private ImageView ivLogo;


/**
 * default and empty constructor
 * The constructor should stay empty
 */
public YourFragment()
{
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);

    this.tvTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
    this.ivLogo = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivLogo);
    return v;
}
```

// ... the rest of your fragment

It should do the job !

hope this help.