# error: cannot find symbol method findviewbyid

Tags: android, fragment, findviewbyid

I have got an app with a tabLayout of 2 fragments with listView and I want to load  the content from a URLConnection with Json but in the Fragment.java file I geht the Error: can't resolve method 'findViewByID(int)'.

```
   public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements URLConnectionResponse {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        CanteenProvider canProv = new CanteenProvider();
        canProv.delegate = this;
        canProv.getDishes(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_canteen_tab_mensa, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void processFinish(List<?> output) {
        ListView canteenList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mensalistView);
        ArrayList<Dish> canteenItemContent = new ArrayList<Dish>();
        canteenItemContent = (ArrayList<Dish>)output;

        CanteenListAdapter canteenAdapter = new CanteenListAdapter(canteenItemContent, this);
        canteenList.setAdapter(canteenAdapter);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow this answer on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37165891/3678308)

```
 private ListView canteenList=null;
  private View view = null;
 @Override 
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_canteen_tab_mensa, container, false);
        canteenList = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.mensalistView);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void processFinish(List<?> output) {

        ArrayList<Dish> canteenItemContent = new ArrayList<Dish>();
        canteenItemContent = (ArrayList<Dish>)output;

        CanteenListAdapter canteenAdapter = new CanteenListAdapter(canteenItemContent, view.getContext());
        canteenList.setAdapter(canteenAdapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use `findViewById` of `View` class. so you can create a global variable for your `ListView` :

```
ListView canteenList;
```

then in your `onViewCreated` initialize your `canteenList`

```
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        canteenList = view.findViewById(R.id.mensalistView);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create one Global variable

> View mainContent;

After that at the time of inflating in **onCreateView** like this

```
mainContent = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_canteen_tab_mensa, container, false);
return mainContent;
```

and at the end with the **reference of the mainContent** you can **findViewById** like this

> ListView canteenList = (ListView) mainContent.findViewById(R.id.mensalistView);